# Как сделать сложный SQL запрос в yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Пытаюсь выполнить такой запрос в yii2:

```
SELECT
    users.phone as phone,
    users.id as user_id
FROM
    users
WHERE
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM cards 
     WHERE cards.user_id = users.id 
       AND cards.expires_at > '2018-10-26') = 0
```

В коде пишу так:

```
$subQuery = CardsWebFit::find()
     ->select('COUNT(*) as count')
     ->where(['cards.user_id' => 'users.id'])
     ->andWhere(['>', 'cards.expires_at', Date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 weeks'))]);

$clientsGroup = UserFitness::find()
     ->select([
         'id' => 'users.id',
         'phone' => 'users.phone',
      ])
      ->where(['=', $subQuery, 0])
      ->asArray()
      ->all();
```

Пробовал писать строкой, еще по всякому, но в результате такая ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

А зачем тут коррелированный подзапрос? Сделайте так:

```
SELECT users.phone as phone,
       users.id as user_id
FROM      users
LEFT JOIN cards ON cards.user_id = users.id 
               AND cards.expires_at > '2018-10-26'
WHERE cards.user_id IS NULL
```

Comment: хорошо, а если мне нужно сделать два запроса к таблице cards? например:

`...
WHERE
     (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cards WHERE cards.user_id = users.id AND cards.expires_at > '2018-10-26') = 0
    AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cards WHERE cards.user_id = users.id AND cards.expires_at < '2018-10-26') > 0`

Comment: я так понимаю, что тогда нужно делать так:
`...
LEFT JOIN cards cards1 ON cards1.user_id = users.id 
AND cards1.expires_at > '2018-10-26'
LEFT JOIN cards cards2 ON cards2.user_id = users.id 
AND cards2.expires_at < '2018-10-26'
WHERE (cards1.user_id IS NULL)
AND (cards2.user_id IS NOT NULL)`
но такой запрос считается дольше чем вот такой:
`...
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM cards 
WHERE cards.user_id = users.id 
AND cards.expires_at > '2018-10-26') = 0 
AND (SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM cards 
WHERE cards.user_id = users.id 
AND cards.expires_at < '2018-10-26') > 0 `

Comment: Просто у пользователя может быть несколько карт, и мне нужно выбрать таких, у которых есть карты с заканчивающимся сроком до определенного числа, и нет карт у которых срок заканчивается позже этого числа.

Comment: @ГенийПриколов Я вам настоятельно рекомендую создать новый вопрос, где сформулировать именно задачу - показать структуру таблиц, пример наполнения, желаемый результат (желательно также создать fiddle с этими данными), и просить помощи в написании нормального запроса. А уж потом, когда запрос будет, создать ещё вопрос, где просить помощи в преобразовании этого запроса в диалект Yii. Сейчас у Вас всё в одной куче, разбираться в которой нет никакого желания.